# Override dynamically created and loaded assembly

Tags: c#, appdomain, roslyn, bridge

Currently i create assemblies for my application dynamically at startup. Is it possible to create new assemblies at runtime and override existing assemblies in the `AppDomain`?

I know that this would be possible if i work with different `AppDomain`s and app domain bridges, but i want to avoid this.

**My aim**

We create an Entity-Framework DB-Context with all models dynamically at application startup. But at runtime maybe the database scheme change, and i want
to have the changes represented in the entity framework dbcontext and models.

Comment: You can't "override" an assembly once it's loaded. What do you mean by *create new assemblies*? Will they be named the same as loaded ones?

Comment: Exactly. I want to compile a new assembly with the same name but add some classes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types from your dynamic assembly are used, then it cannot overridden, but if not used, it will eventually be unloaded. Then it will be possible to override it.

Comment: Ok, they will be used. Do you know any alternative methods to achive my aim?

Comment: It is very interesting situation,
Maybe try to make the event a change the database schema, then the application will reinitialized, if it is possible in your case.
Option is more difficult, it is possible to generate not only the implementation of the class, but also a smart proxy that will use implementation, if the proxy sees that the realization change, it will create a  class from new assembly and will use it.